# Improve performance of unnest function of array column (index?)

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table schema with an array column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reports ( modalities varchar(16)[] );
```

I now want to extract all distinct modalities from the whole table. For that I use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(modalities) AS distinct_modalities FROM reports;
```

Unfortunately, this table is large (millions of rows). Is there something I can do to make this query faster (I have to do this in a web app quite often)? I read somewhere that a `GIN` index won't help me with `unnest`. Is that correct?

Comment: How many modalities are there per row? And how many unique modalities do you expect across your whole dataset?

Comment: Why do you use an array in the first place? A standard 3NF model would have solved your issue.

Comment: Store the modalities in a separate table. Create a relationship table between them and your reports instead of storing them in an array. You can then just scan the modalities table when you need all the currently available values.

Comment: I guess you are right. Some denormalized table structure seems to be a better fit here. Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: 2 or 3 tables would be the normalised structure. It's the structure with the array that is denormalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really anything you can do with such a data model except to get lots of RAM and crank up `work_mem` to speed up the sort.

If you had stored the values in individual rows instead of an array, an index on the table would have helped.